# E: Package 'php8.0-mysql' has no installation candidate

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, php-8

I have ubuntu 22 version and trying to install the PHP V 8.0 but I am not able to install it.

Below are the steps I am trying

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

> Error:  Adding deb entry to
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-lunar.list Adding disabled
> deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-lunar.list
> Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php.gpg with
> fingerprint 14AA40EC0831756756D7F66C4F4EA0AAE5267A6C Get:1
> https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/symfony/stable/deb/ubuntu impish
> InRelease [5,120 B] Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar
> InRelease      Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates
> InRelease [109 kB]         Ign:4
> https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu lunar InRelease
> Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu lunar Release
> 404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443] Get:6
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
> Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease [109
> kB] Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates/main amd64
> DEP-11 Metadata [81.2 kB] Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> lunar-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [52.7 kB] Get:10
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11
> Metadata [13.2 kB] Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> lunar-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,404 B] Get:12
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security/universe amd64 DEP-11
> Metadata [6,564 B] Reading package lists... Done
> E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu
> lunar Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
> repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
> default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
> configuration details.

If I try to install using

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0
```

It installed the php but mysql is not working and when I try to run the command
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysql

> E: Package 'php8.0-mysql' has no installation candidate

Answer (score -1):

This version of ubuntu is not released yet. Try the LTS version.